# Upgrading/downgrading subscription SKU's in flutter with in_app_purchase.dart

Tags: flutter

I'm using the in_app_purchase flutter package to manage subscriptions in flutter.

I can create subscriptions fine using

```
final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: productToPurchase);
InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
```

but I can't find any parameters to be able to specify an old SKU to be able to upgrade/downgrade the subscription.

I've looked at in_app_purchase.dart and billing_client_wrappers.dart but can't find anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: Create an issue for this on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new).

Comment: Seems it's not there yet as just found this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32395#issuecomment-519656412

Comment: You can also give a thumbs up to the original comment on that issue. This usually increases priority (implementing it yourself works too of course, that would be a very nice contribution).